# Datagrid RowDetails not being updated

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

I'm having a problem getting the `RowDetailsTemplate` to update when modifying the collection ("Items") that a `DataGrid` is bound to.  The collection is being modified from within a view model.  When I modify the *contents* of one of the bound items, the change is updated in both the DataGridRow and RowDetailsTemplate.  E.g.

```
Items[i].Name = "new name";  // RowDetailsTemplate gets updated
```

**But** if I assign one of the items to a totally new object the DataGridRow updated, but the RowDetailsTemplate doesn't get updated. E.g.

```
Items[i] = new Model {Name = "new name"};  // RowDetailsTemplate NOT updated
```

The only thing I thought at first was that I needed to add a listener to the CollectionChanged event of the bound Items and explicitly raise a property change notification. E.g

```
Items = new ObeservableCollection<Model>();
Items.CollectionChanged += (o,e) => OnNotifyPropertyChanged("Items");
```

but that didn't work.

My XAML bindings look like this:

```
<DataGrid DataContext="{StaticResource viewmodel}" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}">
  <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

Why is the `DataGridRow` notified of the changed Item but not the `RowDetailsTemplate`?!

**Update**
Doing a delete/add instead of modifying the collection works.  E.g.

```
Items.Remove(Items[i]);
Items.Add (new Model {Name = "new name"});  // RowDetailsTemplate updated OK
```

(Oh and the Model class of course implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.)

Seems like this might be an issue where I need to refresh the DataContext of the details view?

Comment: Got this exact issue on .NET 4.6 so it's still a problem. The workaround (Remove, then insert) solves it for me, but I don't like it...

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you:

```
Items.RemoveAt(i);
Items.Insert(i,(new Model {Name = "new name"});
```

Would have the same effect.

Comment: And like I said, the problem is not with the `DataGridRow` - that updates fine.  It's with the `RowDetailsTemplate`.

Comment: I got it now. Thanks. I'm doing some research.

Comment: I'm using a similar workaround right now - but it's just that a cludgey workaround that requires the viewmodel to be coded in a way that is adapting to a particular behavior of the view.  I'm not really looking for a workaround - the question is really trying to get at the root problem.

Comment: Sure. It looks like a problem with  .NET implementation. I don't know the answer, unfortunately. I'd start by looking into .NET IL.

Comment: Thanks I'll keep digging. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had to insert such a dirty hack in CellEditEnding handler  code:

```
DataTemplate temp = ProfileDataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate;
ProfileDataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate = null;
ProfileDataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate = temp;
```

It works, Row Detail is updated, but I also want to know how masters update RowDetails.